# C++ - vector <class> and std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, c++11

I am working on translating a program from matlab code to C++ where I have to use opencv libs on Linux (gcc version 4.9.2)

So I am trying to translate this line of matlab code:

```
repeatedMat = repmat(originalMat,[1 1 k]);
```

and the last code I wrote is this:

```
void repeat(cv::Mat img, std::vector <cv::Mat> &output, uint32_t nx, uint32_t ny, uint32_t z)
{
    cv::Mat tmpMat = cv::repeat(img, nx, ny);
    output = std::vector <Mat> (z);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < output.size(); i++)
        output.insert(output.end(), tmpMat);
}
```

The problem is that I always run into **std::bad_alloc** error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

I don't know exactly why but I am thinking about some memory leak..
Is there a better (and working) way to do this ?

Comment: all of your code should be reduced to `vector <Mat> output(z, img);`

Comment: In addition to that, if you want to add an element to the end of `vector`, you should use `push_back` method.

Comment: Every time the loop is iterated, the `output` vector grows, so the loop *never* reaches the end.... until the program is out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, the condition of a `for` loop is evaluated in every iteration, so if you add a new element at the end of the vector, it grows by 1, so in the next iteration the counter `i` will not reach it. It should be something like:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < z; i++)
    output.insert(output.end(), tmpMat);
```

But as rahnema1 said in the comments, you don't need to do that. You can create a vector with `z` copies of the same element without copy them:

```
output = std::vector <Mat> (z, tmpMat);
```

Also, because you have labelled your question as "c++11", let me another additional suggestions: return the vector by value, the compiler will avoid the copy.

```
std::vector <cv::Mat> repeat(cv::Mat img, uint32_t nx, uint32_t ny, uint32_t z)
{
    return std::vector<cv::Mat>(z, cv::repeat(img, nx, ny));
}
```